# PHP stream_resolve_include_path undefined php 5.5

Tags: php, xampp

While using XAMPP with `PHP > 5.5`, it throws an error :

```
call to undefined function stream_resolve_include_path
```

But, it is defined because if I try to inject my own function with the same name it throws :

```
Cannot overwrite constant stream_resolve_include_path
```

Anyone run across this problem in xampp? Or can confirm or deny in your xampp setup?

(I have the apache rewrite mod on).

Comment: Didn't encounter this problem on trying with xampp v5.6.8 on windows 7, I also have my apache rewrite mod on

Comment: Hmmm. I never figured it out. I used is_dir() for part of a partial workaround.